# Unable to test onChange mock method with shallow and with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I can`t deal to solve the onChange testing, also dealt with problems with the onClick but somehow succeed to slove it.
I have followed the docs of Enzyme and Jest and it didn't work, followed 2 courses on Pluralsight and yet the result was the same, read many articles and solution here but yet it won't pass.
I have found out about the Deprecation of.simulate() and tried props.onChange.

I will be happy for any kind of help.

This is the component I would like to test :

```
    const [details, setdetails] = useState(
        {
            fullName: '',
            email: '',
            phone: ''
        }
    )
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [isValid, setValid] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = event => {
        let { name, value } = event.target;
        console.log(value, name, event.target);
        event.preventDefault();
        setdetails(prevDetails => ({
            ...prevDetails,
            [name]: value
        }));

    }
   return (
        <div className="contact" id="contact">
            <div className="logo"></div>
            <div className="contact-title">
                <h6>PLEASE LEAVE YOUR DETAILS BELOW AND WE’LL CONTACT YOU</h6>
            </div>
            <div className="fields">
                <form>
                    <div className="input-field">
                       <label>Full Name:</label>
                       <input name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name" onChange={handleChange}
                   />
                       <div className="text-danger">{errors.fullName}</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="input-field">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={handleChange} 
                  />
                    <div className="text-danger">{errors.email}</div></div>
                 <div className="input-field">
                     <label>Phone:</label> 
                     <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" onChange={handleChange} 
                 />
                     <div className="text-danger">{errors.phone}</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <button type="submmit" 
                          className="btn-dark button"
                          onClick={handleClick}
                        >Submit</button>
                </div>
             </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Testing tries:

```
describe('', () => {
    it('', () => {
        let mockOnChange = jest.fn();
        const props = {
            mockOnChange: mockOnChange
        }
        let wrapper = shallow(<Contact {...props} />)
        console.log(wrapper.debug());
        let event = {
            preventDefault: () => { },
            name: 'fullName',
            target: {
                value: 'test'
            }

        }
        wrapper.find('input').at(0).props().onChange({ event })
        expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test');
    })
    it('second assertion', () => {
        let mockOnChange = jest.fn();
        let name = 'fullName';
        let value = 'test';
        let wrapper = shallow(<Contact onChange={mockOnChange} />)
        console.warn(mockOnChange);
        wrapper.instance().onChange({ target: { name, value } });
        expect(mockOnChange).toHaveBeenCalled('test');
    })
    it('', () => {
        let handleChange = jest.fn();
        let mockName = 'fullName';
        let mockValue = 'test';
        let wrapper;
        wrapper = shallow(<Contact onChange={handleChange} />);
        wrapper.find('input').at(0).simulate('change', {
            preventDefault: () => { },
            target: {
                name: mockName,
                value: mockValue
            }
        })
        expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith("test");

    })
})


describe("simulate onchange input fileds", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let mockOnChange;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockOnChange = jest.fn();
        const props = {
            mockOnChange: mockOnChange
        }
        wrapper = shallow(<Contact {...props} />);
    });
    it('first assertion', () => {

        wrapper.find('input').at(0).simulate('change', {
            preventDefault: () => { },
            target: { value: 'test' }
        })
        expect(mockOnChange).toBeCalledWith("test");
    })

    it('should call onChange prop', () => {
        const event = {
            preventDefault: () => { },
            target: {
                name: 'fullName',
                value: 'test'
            }
        };
        const component = shallow(<Contact onChange={mockOnChange} />);
        component.find('input').at(0).props().onChange('change', event);
        expect(mockOnChange).toBeCalledWith('test');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your component does not call `props.mockOnChange` or `props.handleChange` or alike. It just takes new value from event, store it in its state and render it as a value for appropriate input.

Also currently your component does not use `details` for rendering at all. I'd expect it looks like

```
<input 
  name="fullName" 
  placeholder="Full Name" 
  onChange={handleChange}
  value={details.fullName}
/>
```

And then we would be able validate this behavior(also pay attention to `event`'s structure, in your code you're setting `name` property outside `target` subobject):

```
it('', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<Contact {...props} />)
    let event = {
        preventDefault: jest.fn(),
        target: {
            name: 'fullName',
            value: 'test'
        }

    }
    wrapper.find('input[name="fullName"]').simulate('change', event)
    expect(wrapper.find('input[name="fullName"]').prop('value')).toBe('test');
    expect(wrapper.find('input[name="email"]').prop('value')).toBe('');
    expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Hey skyboyer, first of all, thanks for answering and for the important notes. poorly even after I have made the changes you wrote it still not passing the test. Failed to parse selector: input[name=fullName]
      
    wrapper.find('input[name=fullName]').simulate('change', event)
               ^
     expect(wrapper.find('input[name=fullName]').prop('value')).toBe('test');
     expect(wrapper.find('input[name=email]').prop('value')).toBe('');
     expect(event.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: When I tried it with the at method, the output was undefined.

Comment: probably it should be with quotes `input[name="fullName"]`. or you can try `.find("input").filter({name: "fullName"})`

Comment: I really appreciate your willingness and the fact you`re answering so fast. I have tried both but, it`s still filed, claiming that the value is undefined. have any idea why? maybe I`m not declaring something right?

Comment: don't see any reason :( so is `prop('value')` `undefined`? or does `.find()` return `undefined`?

Comment: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "test"
    Received: undefined                                                                                         > 96 |         expect(wrapper.find("input").filter({ name: "fullName"}).prop('value')).toBe('test');
         |                                                                                  ^

Comment: don`t know what else to do

Comment: I missed really basic thing: your component does not render `details.fullName` into `value` attribute. So that's why it was not working in test. Besides it may work to you at first, current version will never allow you setting value programmatically without you change code. So better do that right now.

Comment: Hey again, thanks for the correction and for every response, did what you wrote, but yet it still not pass the test but now it because the value isn't changing.  it weird because the function is working can't understand why the test is failing

Comment: oh, only today I was able to run it with debugger and found out that your put `name` in wrong place inside `event`(not into `target` but as 1st level prop). Updated answer, check it out. Test has passed to me.